# Is there a way to force Scrapy into the parse method even if there is an unhandled exception?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, twisted, scrapy

I have a fairly complex multiprocessed program that uses Scrapy. It works perfectly about 95% of the time, but occasionally I will get unhandled exceptions from Twisted when it hits bad sites that result in DNSLookupError/TCPTimedOutError.

This wouldn't be an issue, but unfortunately, these errors result in Scrapy skipping the BaseSpider parse method, where I've set up a Queue to handle the responses. Since it skips the Queue, I have no way of figuring out which URL's were skipped.

Is there a way to always ensure that every Scrapy request ends up in that parse method? All I need is a way to access those failed response objects and put them into a Queue.

Here is an example of my spider code:

```
class SeerSpider(BaseSpider):
    """Scrapy-based html retrieval system."""

    name = "SeerSpider"

    def __init__(self, spider_queue, url_list):
        self.queue = spider_queue
        self.allowed_domains = []
        self.start_urls = []
        for url in url_list:
            self.allowed_domains.append(str(urlparse(url).netloc))
            self.start_urls.append(url)
        super(SeerSpider, self).__init__()

    def parse(self, response):
        """Extracts information from each website in start_urls."""
        self.queue.put(response)
```

As you can see, it's extremely basic.

Later on, the Queue is processed like this:

```
while True:
    response = spider_queue.get()
    ### DO STUFF HERE ###
    results_queue.put(result)
```

And then...

```
while True:
    try:
        result = results_queue.get(True, 60)
    except:
        print 'HALP', sys.exc_info()
        result = ['ERROR']
    self.results.append(result)
    counter -= 1
    if counter <= 0 or self.exit == True:
        for process in process_list:
            process.terminate()
        break
```

I added in the Queue timeout as a temporary solution so it wouldn't hang indefinitely as it waits for non-existent items in the Queue. If I can just guarantee that some kind of response object will enter the Queue for each URL in the start_urls list, it would solve all my problems.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a job for scrapy middleware and `process_spider_exception` method, take a look at [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.SpiderMiddleware.process_spider_exception). Hope that helps.

Comment: No, I added a custom middleware but the errors aren't being handled. I get a bunch of these every time I run the program, and it prevents the Queue from completing:
Unhandled error in Deferred: Unhandled Error
Failure: twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 10060: etc... etc...

Comment: I figured it out, the middleware was the right track, but it was the downloader middleware not the scrapy middleware. After I implemented a downloader middleware with the process_exception method, I managed to get it working.

Comment: Good news! Consider adding an answer for future generations :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, the middleware was the right track, but it was the downloader middleware not the scrapy middleware. After I implemented a downloader middleware with the process_exception method, I managed to get it working.

Code is here:

```
class SpiderFailSignal(object):

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        response = Response(request.url, status=666, body='error')
        spider.queue.put(response)
        return response
```

then I added

```
settings.overrides['DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES'] = {'seerspider.SpiderFailSignal': 901}
```

and it worked.

Although, I also ended up adding a dummy value to the queue once the scrapy spider_idle signal fired, then created an if statement to exit the queue once it came across that item. So both of those solutions together = all fixed.